# Is it possible to update the timestamp when another cell in the same row gets updated?

Tags: google-sheets

I am using `Google Spreadsheets` and what I am trying to do is update the cells that contain a `timestamp` in the `Time last Updated` column each time I update a cell in the same row.

Is there any way I can achieve that?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not tested but something like this should work. Since you didn't provide any details, you will have to change some variables according to your needs.

```
function onEdit(e) {

var startCol = 2, 
    endCol = 10,
    tsCol = 11, //this is the column where the timestamp will appear
    startRow = 2,
    sheetName = 'Sheet1', //this is the name of the sheet you want the script to work on.
    curSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
//exit script when edits are made another sheet, or in the first row, or before col 2 or after col 10
if (curSheet.getName() !== sheetName || e.range.columnStart < startCol || e.range.columStart > endCol || e.range.rowStart < startRow) return;
curSheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, tsCol)
    .setValue(new Date());
```

}

Comment: Forgot to mention: format the col with the timestamp as you wish: date, date/time, or time.